# how to create a collection in controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I need to create a data collection, which will be recording as many times as the foreach runs, what is happening to me is that I only record the data from the last time the foreach runs. how can I solve?

```
foreach($proposedphasesizes as $proposedphasesize)
{
    $customizations = $proposedphasesize->customizations()->get();
    $counter = $proposedphasesize->customizations()->count();

    foreach($customizations as $customization)
    {
        $labels = collect();
        //return $proposedphase . 'separador' . $proposedphasesize . 'separador' . $customization;
        if($customization['quantity'] != null)
        {
            $labels->push((object)  [
                "id" => $customization['quantity']
            ]);

        }
        else
            $labels->push((object)  [
                "id_1" => $customization['quantity']
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Collection every iteration of the inner loop, so the Collection will only have the data from one iteration of that loop.

You should create the Collection outside the loops, and just add to it from inside the loops.